# tune z3 to try lower numbers first

Tags: parameters, z3

I have an smt model with several integers, all of which I have bounded between 0 and N.  Though it is remotely possible that they will be N or near N, the are almost always going to be very close to 0.  Maybe 80% of the time I need them to be 0,1 or 2...something like that.

Also, a lot of the integers can be ignored if some key integers take a lower value, so it seems to me that if I could tune z3 to start at the lower bound and try the smaller models with smaller values first, I could improve my execution times.

I've tried to understand the options in 'z3 -p' but haven't found a way to customize the solving strategy to approach my queries this way.  Is it possible to tune z3 to try lower numbers first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a real solution in context of standard usage of Z3.
I am currently developing optimization features to Z3, which allows posing queries to get minimal/maximal values. You can do this with multiple objectives. 
Unfortunately, getting real optimals can be quite expensive so it does not replace a simple heuristic knob.